# Can't find static_pages_spec.rb in spec/requests directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm going through the Hartl tutorial for rails and ran into a road block I can't figure out. I'm at the first step to generating an integration test (Rspec). I entered:

```
 rails generate integration_test static_pages
```

and then got

```
Waymond-MacBook-Pro:sample_app wayway$ rails generate integration_test static_pages
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:229:in `default_controller_and_action': missing :controller (ArgumentError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:116:in `normalize_options!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:64:in `initialize'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1443:in `new'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1443:in `add_route'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1422:in `decomposed_match'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1403:in `block in match'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1394:in `match'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:601:in `map_method'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:562:in `get'
from /Users/waystylez1/rails_projects/sample_app/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `instance_exec'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:341:in `eval_block'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:319:in `draw'
from /Users/waystylez1/rails_projects/sample_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/waystylez1/rails_projects/sample_app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

and was supposed to get static_pages_spec.rb in the spec/requests directory. It's not in there  so I'm guessing my routing is wrong? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

edit. this is from config/routes.rb

```
   SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
   get "static_pages/..."
   get "static_pages/home"
   get "static_pages/help"
   # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
   # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

   # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   # root 'welcome#index'

   # Example of regular route:
   #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

   # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
   #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

   # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
   #   resources :products

   # Example resource route with options:
   #   resources :products do
   #     member do
   #       get 'short'
   #       post 'toggle'
   #     end
   #
   #     collection do
   #       get 'sold'
   #     end
   #   end

   # Example resource route with sub-resources:
   #   resources :products do
   #     resources :comments, :sales
   #     resource :seller
   #   end

   # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
   #   resources :products do
   #     resources :comments
   #     resources :sales do
   #       get 'recent', on: :collection
   #     end
   #   end

   # Example resource route with concerns:
   #   concern :toggleable do
   #     post 'toggle'
   #   end
   #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
   #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

   # Example resource route within a namespace:
   #   namespace :admin do
   #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
   #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
   #     resources :products
   #   end
    end
```

Comment: can you paste your whole routes file?

Comment: Not sure if that's the right route info you're requesting. Sorry, I'm a noob.

Comment: You should post the entire contents of `config/routes.rb`. That's where you're getting your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `config/routes.rb` file has a small mistake:

```
 SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
   # Get rid of this line, as it's not valid
   # get "static_pages/..."
   get "static_pages/home"
   get "static_pages/help"
 end
```

It seems as though the Hartl tutorial has a line like this:

```
  $ rails generate controller static_pages ...
```

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code-generating_pages

Those extra dots are superfluous. You can use that space to generate the `help` or `home` actions. For example:

```
  $ rails generate controller static_pages help home
```

Comment: edited that and got this in after running: rails generate integration_test static_pages . I got this error: `<top (required)>': undefined method `get' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

Comment: Post your error to your original question. I need to see more of the stack trace.

Comment: I just got it working. Farley, thank you so much. Thank you for the explanation too. I would vote you up if I could but I need to get better at coding lol.

Comment: You can mark my answer as the solution :) That would definitely help.